# Fixing unknown library popup on Windows Zoom C++ SDK

Tags: c++, windows, vcpkg, zoom-sdk

I’m developing in the C++ Zoom SDK on Windows an application that uses a separate gRPC application connection. I’ve integrated the code into the demo app without issue, but whenever I run the application I get a popup now that says:

**sdk.dll is using cares.dll from an unknown publisher. Are you sure you want to run this software?**

The cares.dll is CAres and is used by the gRPC library and comes from vcpkg so I know there isn’t malicious code in it, however, I can’t find a way to disable this message.

I’ve also tried registering the `Disable3rdModuleVerify` registry entry but the message still pops up.

Zoom SDK version: v5.11.1.6653
Windows Version: Windows 11 22H2 22621.1555

Comment: This is intended, see [here](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/i-got-a-warning-when-i-use-initsdk/66426/12). You can [patch](https://fatrodzianko.com/2020/04/07/unprivileged-user-persistence-with-zoom/) `Zoom.exe` or in your case `sdk.dll` to get rid of the message.